# What is the meaning of the title?

Tags: barakamon

What is the meaning of the title "Barakamon" from the anime *Barakamon*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title "Barakamon" means "cheerful/energetic person" (元気者) in the local provincial Gotou Island dialect (this seems to be the case with just about all the episode titles), where most of the series takes place, on one of the islands off the western coast of Kyushu.

The first episode of the anime is titled "ばらかこどん" (Baraka kodon, meaning "[a] cheerful/energetic kid"), which is obviously referring to Naru.

[image: Baraka Kodon]

Answer (score 3):

The title *Barakamon*, as stated from [ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-07-03/barakamon-mijikamon-short-anime-episode-0-posted/.76261), means "**energetic one**". The "**energetic one**" must be referring to Naru Kotoishi. Naru is one of the major characters in the story. She is a hyperactive and cheerful kid whom Handa meets in the beginning of the story. Everyday, Naru comes over the Handa house and learns new things from him. Naru tells him the wonders of living a country life, the things she love about the islands. Eventually, Handa begins to appreciate the country and learns the value of friendship, thanks to Naru.